# hyperledger fabric excute this command peer lifecycle chaincode install sacc.tar.gz

Tags: go

Error: chaincode install failed with status: 500 - failed to invoke backing implementation of 'InstallChaincode': could not build chaincode: docker build failed: docker image build failed: docker build failed: Error returned from build: 1 "/chaincode/input/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-cluster/chaincode/go/vendor/golang.org/x/net/http2/transport.go:19:2: cannot find package "io/fs" in any of:
/chaincode/input/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-cluster/chaincode/go/vendor/io/fs (vendor tree)
/usr/local/go/src/io/fs (from $GOROOT)
/chaincode/input/src/io/fs (from $GOPATH)
/go/src/io/fs

it is the first time i used it. i hope someone can help me solve the question.